# Select Json Object as nvarchar(max) in JSON_VALUE

Tags: sql-server, open-json, json-value

I do not know how to extract a path of JSON as `nvarchar(max)`. It always returns null.

I do not want to specify the fields to get because I have no idea the field names. So the idea here is select it as a string and process them later.

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) =
'{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName" : "doe",
    "address"  : {
        "streetAddress": "naist street",
        "city"         : "Nara",
        "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
    }
}'

SELECT [Type]
FROM OPENJSON( @json, '$.address' ) 
WITH ([Type] NVARCHAR(max) '$');
```

The expected result is that the `Type` column contains the whole JSON object of `address` as string

```
{ "streetAddress": "naist street", "city": "Nara", "postalCode" : "630-0192" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute the statement in a different way. Note, that when you use `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema you need to use `AS JSON` to specify that the referenced property contains an inner JSON object or array. Of course, you may use `JSON_QUERY()` to get the same result:

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) =
'{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName" : "doe",
    "address"  : {
        "streetAddress": "naist street",
        "city"         : "Nara",
        "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
    }
}'
```

Statement (using `OPENJSON()`):

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json) 
WITH ([Type] NVARCHAR(max) '$.address' AS JSON);
```

Statement (using `JSON_QUERY()`)

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(@json, '$.address') AS [Type]
```

Result:

```
Type
{
        "streetAddress": "naist street",
        "city"         : "Nara",
        "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
    }
```